# How soluble is water ice in liquid H2S?

Tags: water, solubility, chemistry-in-fiction

This seems to be ridiculously hard to research, as Google only wants to give me results about dissolving H2S in water (rather than the other way around)--and when I tried to get around that by looking for information on H2O/H2S phase diagrams, or eutectic mixtures, all I could get was single-substance phase diagrams for one or the other, and information about deep eutectic solvents for H2S scrubbing.

So... does anybody know how soluble water ice is in liquid H2S at -70 to -80 Celsius?

Comment: I am curious why you may need that. I assume very few chemists would be willing to measure it.

Comment: @Poutnik Because I am an SF author and it turns out that whether or not ice will dissolve is plot-relevant. (It's the sort of thing Hal Clement might've written, except much better than me.) I would've thought someone would measure on the basis that it'd be relevant to producing pure anhydrous chemicals for industrial purposes.

Comment: Now that's a responsible approach to world building.

Comment: The fact that gaseous H2S is just slightly soluble in water gives a hint about ice solubility in liquid H2S.

Comment: I think it is **virtually insoluble**.

Comment: I'm sure there is someone somewhere who uses cold H2S, but for typical industrial applications it is liquified by simple compression rather than chilling. If anhydrous is needed, H2O is removed from the gas phase before compression, so there is no need to know anything about the solubility of H2O in cold H2S and therefore not much motivation to measure it.

Comment: I would guess [the hydrogen sulfide would rather dissolve into the ice.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clathrate_hydrate)

Comment: @OscarLanzi Wouldn't clathrate rather form in a "cocrystallisation"? Hmm, maybe ice would turn into clathrate if pressure was high enough?

Comment: @Logan R. Kearsley What pressure range do you have in mind?

Comment: What is an industrial application for liquid H2S ? The oil industry produces mega tons of H2S which is converted to elemental sulfur and sulfuric acid, generally; never liquid.

Comment: @blacksmith37 https://www.indsci.com/en/industrial-scientific-gas-types-hydrogen-sulfide-h2s
I suppose none of the applications listed there would require chilled liquid, though; too bad for me!

Comment: @Mithoron Between one and two atmospheres; hence the low temperature range to produce liquification.

Comment: Well, under the circumstance - temp. and pressure. I still say if you simply drop some ice into liquid H2S, then nothing happens, at least not more then if you ditched it into cold diethyl ether. I think it's a bit of an X & Y problem though. Your idea is using H2S an alternative for water for life in very cold environment, perhaps?

Comment: @Mithoron Yup! Of the algae-and-bacteria variety, anyway. I got through 4 awesome experimental papers on its solvent properties and reactions with various organic molecules... and then realized, crap, none of these actually mention water!

Comment: I think liquid NH3 would be a safer bet. It's actually sometimes used as solvents in reaction. Did you see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry#Non-water_solvents

Comment: @Mithoron It certainly is... but everybody else thinks so, too, and I've used that conceit myself, so I'm looking for something more exotic. I have indeed seen that wikipedia page, and read most of the footnote references (and some of *their* references)!

Comment: Still, the more exotic, the harder - for example the clathrates issue, afaik not a problem with NH3. Heck, iirc there was a novel with FOOF as a solvent! Better go for accuracy then originality - what actual consequences of ideas would be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134150/discussion-between-mithoron-and-logan-r-kearsley).